# why does time subtraction returns 1 instead of 0 after echoed

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this table in my view

```
  duty   |  exact   |  undertime
12:00:00 | 12:00:00 | 01:00:00
```

undertime is the result of `$hour = $duty - $exact`, and when i

```
echo date("H:i:s",$hour);
```

it echoed 01:00:00, im expecting 00:00:00 for this. What did i miss?

here are my code, i use foreach because the duty and exact datas are from my database query.

```
<?php foreach($unique_date as $unique_dates):?>  
                <tr>
                  <td align="center" colspan="2">
                      <?php echo date($unique_dates['dtr_date']);?>
                  </td>
                  <td align="center" colspan="2">
                      <?php $timediffs = $unique_dates['timediffs'];
                            echo $timediffs;
                      ?>
                  </td>
                  <td align="center" colspan="2">
                      <?php $exact_total_sched = $unique_dates['exact_total_sched'];
                            echo $exact_total_sched;
                      ?>
                  </td>
                  <?php                         
                        $duty = strtotime($timediffs);
                        $exact = strtotime($exact_total_sched);
                  ?>
                  <?php
                        if($duty < $exact)
                        {
                          echo "<td align=\"center\" colspan=\"2\">";
                                #UNDERTIME  
                                $hour1 = $exact-$duty;
                                echo date("H:i:s",$hour1);
                          echo "</td>";
                          echo "<td align=\"center\" colspan=\"2\">";
                          echo date("00:00:00");
                          echo "</td>";
                        }
                     else if($duty > $exact)
                       {
                          echo "<td align=\"center\" colspan=\"2\">";
                           echo date("00:00:00");
                          echo "</td>";
                          echo "<td align=\"center\" colspan=\"2\">";
                                #OVERTIME
                                $hour2 = $duty-$exact;
                               echo date("H:i:s",$hour2);
                          echo "</td>";
                       }
                      else if($duty == $exact)
                       {
                          echo "<td align=\"center\" colspan=\"2\">";
                                $hour3 = $duty-$exact;
                          echo date("H:i:s",$hour3);
                          echo "</td>";
                          echo "<td align=\"center\" colspan=\"2\">";
                          echo date("00:00:00");
                          echo "</td>";
                       }
                      ?> 
                </tr>

              <?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: Are these values strings? unix timestamps? DateTime objects? How are you doing the subtraction? SHOW CODE and initial data values for $duty and $exact.... also, what timezone are you in? and do you have daylight saving?

Comment: I think problem is with timezone. In which time zone you working

Comment: @saty - that was my thinking: from string arithmetic, '12:00:00' - '12:00:00' would cast to 12 - 12 giving 0; then using that as the unix timestamp for date() would adjust to the defined timezone and daylight saving.... which for the UK is currently +01:00

Comment: ahh.. Mark Baker im from philippines so how should i convert the timestamp here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `DateTime` function along with `date_diff` as

```
$date1=new DateTime("12:00:00");
$date2=new DateTime("12:00:00");
$diff = date_diff($date2,$date1);
echo $diff->format('%H:%i:%s');
```

Comment: something went wrong when i used ur code, Error says "Message: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to int"

Answer (score 1):

```
$duty=date_create("12:00:00");
$exact=date_create("12:00:00");
$diff=date_diff($duty,$exact);
echo $diff->format("%H:%i:%s");die;
```

Comment: i dont know if i can do that since the time in my table is dynamic. They came from my database so anytime soon they can be changed

Comment: So you can just pass the value in a variable to this method why not?